Default settings for videos on Stream on SharePoint Online
Is there a way to set the default settings for all new uploaded videos to a list/site or the whole SharePoint. It is quite a mess turning off settings like translations or comments on every video manually. We really would like to define defaults somewhere.

No I'm afraid...
